# How can I run E2E tests on Amazon Linux AMI?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, protractor

I'm using Protractor to run end to end tests, and everything runs fine in Chrome and Firefox on Ubuntu.  When I try to run the tests with PhantomJS, it says it's not able to find the elements.  I'm using Angular v1.2.15.  My goal is to run the tests on an Amazon Linux AMI, so I either have to get PhantomJS working or install Chrome or Firefox, which seems really complicated. I've read that PhantomJS isn't ideal for testing on EC2 instances, but is there a browser I should use? This is the error and stack trace that I'm getting:

```
UnknownError: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with id 'username'","request":    {"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, image/png","Connection":"Keep-Alive","Content-    Length":"33","Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-    8","Host":"localhost:28418"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"    {\"using\":\"id\",\"value\":\"username\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":    {"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/elem    ent","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"",    "source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":    ["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/7e7e8860-cb0a-11e3-b0d0-117406720391/element"}}
Build info: version: '2.40.0', revision: 'fbe29a9', time: '2014-02-19 20:54:28'
System info: host: 'Brendan-Kirby-BN', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch:     'amd64', os.version: '3.11.0-18-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
   Stacktrace:
     Error
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/brendankirby/ads/apps/client/test/ads-login-spec.js:4:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/brendankirby/ads/apps/client/test/ads-login-spec.js:3:1)
At async task:
      UnknownError: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with id         'username'","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, image/png","Connection":"Keep-    Alive","Content-Length":"33","Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-    8","Host":"localhost:28418"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"    {\"using\":\"id\",\"value\":\"username\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":    {"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/elem    ent","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"",    "source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":    ["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/7e7e8860-cb0a-11e3-b0d0-117406720391/element"}}
Build info: version: '2.40.0', revision: 'fbe29a9', time: '2014-02-19 20:54:28'
System info: host: 'Brendan-Kirby-BN', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch:     'amd64', os.version: '3.11.0-18-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
==== async task ====
WebDriver.findElement(By.id("username"))
    at Protractor.findElement     (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/protractor.js:748:25)
    at Object.elementFinder.(anonymous function) [as sendKeys]     (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/protractor.js:103:24)
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/brendankirby/ads/apps/client/test/ads-login-spec.js:9:32)
```

And here is the phantomjs log:

```
[INFO  - 2014-04-23T17:12:47.902Z] GhostDriver - Main - running on port 28418
[INFO  - 2014-04-23T17:12:48.363Z] Session [7e7e8860-cb0a-11e3-b0d0-117406720391] -    page.settings -     {"XSSAuditingEnabled":false,"javascriptCanCloseWindows":true,"javascriptCanOpenWindows":true    ,"javascriptEnabled":true,"loadImages":true,"localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled":false,"userAgent    ":"Mozilla/5.0 (Unknown; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, like Gecko)         PhantomJS/1.9.7 Safari/534.34","webSecurityEnabled":true}
[INFO  - 2014-04-23T17:12:48.363Z] Session [7e7e8860-cb0a-11e3-b0d0-117406720391] -     page.customHeaders:  - {}
[INFO  - 2014-04-23T17:12:48.363Z] Session [7e7e8860-cb0a-11e3-b0d0-117406720391] -     Session.negotiatedCapabilities -     {"browserName":"phantomjs","version":"1.9.7","driverName":"ghostdriver","driverVersion":"1.1    .0","platform":"linux-unknown-    64bit","javascriptEnabled":true,"takesScreenshot":true,"handlesAlerts":false,"databaseEnable    d":false,"locationContextEnabled":false,"applicationCacheEnabled":false,"browserConnectionEn    abled":false,"cssSelectorsEnabled":true,"webStorageEnabled":false,"rotatable":false,"acceptS    slCerts":false,"nativeEvents":true,"proxy":{"proxyType":"direct"}}
[INFO  - 2014-04-23T17:12:48.364Z] SessionManagerReqHand - _postNewSessionCommand - New     Session Created: 7e7e8860-cb0a-11e3-b0d0-117406720391
[ERROR - 2014-04-23T17:12:50.308Z] Session [7e7e8860-cb0a-11e3-b0d0-117406720391] -     page.onError - msg: SyntaxError: Parse error
[ERROR - 2014-04-23T17:12:50.308Z] Session [7e7e8860-cb0a-11e3-b0d0-117406720391] -     page.onError - stack:
[ERROR - 2014-04-23T17:12:50.314Z] Session [7e7e8860-cb0a-11e3-b0d0-117406720391] -     page.onError - msg: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: angular
[ERROR - 2014-04-23T17:12:50.314Z] Session [7e7e8860-cb0a-11e3-b0d0-117406720391] -     page.onError - stack:
  (anonymous function) (http://ads-qa.bnservers.com/scripts/a267e5f1.scripts.js:1)
[ERROR - 2014-04-23T17:12:50.686Z] WebElementLocator - _handleLocateCommand - Element(s)     NOT Found: GAVE UP. Search Stop Time: 1398273170644
[INFO  - 2014-04-23T17:12:52.211Z] ShutdownReqHand - _handle - About to shutdown
```

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Comment: Sorry, I don't recall what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

I use a headless selenium server in the cloud, it provides Chrome & Firefox even though there is no real DISPLAY. I've just moved the config files here: https://github.com/elgalu/headless